# can AWS load balancer auto restart out of service images?

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, high-availability

I have set up a load balancer with two instances in two availability zone

I set up an health check to ping a specific page of my webapp

now I'm trying to find if the load balancer health check could be used to automatically restart one instance after it's flagged out of service.

I'm already receiving the notification and log are to be put on a separate system, so all I can do after an instance fails and a ticket is created is to reboot it. any way to do that automatically? I can't find such an option and google searches are filled with basic howtos

Comment: Look into auto-scaling groups.